# how to remove kworker process on certain cpu core

Tags: c++, arrays, milliseconds

I have a process (testprogram) bind to core 50, and i dont want any context_switch.

1. /etc/default/grub: add with "isolcpus=50 nohz_full=50 rcu_nocbs=50"
2. ps -eLo psr,comm | grep '50'

0 watchdog/50
50 migration/50
50 ksoftirqd/50
50 kworker/50:0
50 kworker/50:0H
0 rcuob/50
11 rcuos/50
50 kworker/50:1
50 testProject

3. "sudo perf record -e sched:sched_switch -T -p PID" will record contex_switch, and i found kworker always take over the core50;

----how can i shut down kworker on core50;

-- i tried /sys/devices/virtual/workqueue/cpumask, but not work

Comment: Any question concerning the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by 1) Compiler used, 2) Version of the compiler used, 3) Optimization settings used when building the program.

Comment: You are not running on a real-time OS, and so execution times are not guaranteed. Your process is still subject to time slicing by the OS process scheduler. If you're measuring wall clock time, it's possible your process was context-switched between time measurements in these cases. You might also see occasional cache misses, depending on what else is sharing CPU time in the operating system.

Comment: Make sure you have a release build with optimizations enabled. Also why do you use `malloc` (and `printf`) in a C++ program? Use [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to allocate arrays dynamically. For getting the sum of an array (vector) use [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: @paddy, thank u, and the code is binded to a cpu isolated and context-switch is shutdown

Comment: For measuring time either use a profiler or something like [nanobench](https://nanobench.ankerl.com/). Or from C++ itself use std::chrono::steady_clock (but then you are still measuring wall time)

Comment: @paddy yes, u are right; although i have make core25 isolated, and close some interrupt, like"isolcpus=25 nohz_full=25 rcu_nocbs=25",but still can't stop context_switch, and i found a kworker/25:2 process always get the cpu  and run; and this cost n ms; but i can't remove this kworker from core25 even after rewrite "/sys/devices/virtual/workqueue/cpumask"